Does static method impact Spring SQL transactions?
I noticed that if I have a method annotated with @Transactional, which calls a static method, which results in database calls, Spring will create two different hibernate sessions and use two different database connections (potentially resulting in deadlock)

Here's how I tested:
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
public class MyTest {

    @Autowrited UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    public void doAction() {

         User user = new User("test", "Test user", new Date());

         userRepository.save(user); //this results in locking some database objects

         Utils.getUserName(user.getId()); //static method which queries the locked object
    }
}

@Setter
public class Utils {
    
    private static UserRepository userRepository; //Setter is called from some @Config

    public static String getUserName(int userId) {
        return userRepository.getUserById(userId).getName();
    }
}

@Repository
public class UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Integer> {
    
    UserEntity getUserById(int id);
}

The above code may result in deadlock, because userRepository.getUserById() creates a new hibernate session instead of reusing the existing one.
The code works however if skip the static method and just call the repository method directly from the test.
Note that the repository method is not annotated with @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW), and I have not customized the transaction manager, so I was expecting the already existing transaction to be reused.
I couldn't find any documentation regarding this behavior. Can anyone provide any explanation or references?

Does Utils.userRepository and MyTest.userRepository points to the same instance?

@talexmovedtoCodidact Yes

How do you know that "Spring will create two different hibernate sessions and use two different database connections"? It shouldn't care about static methods. Session attached to thread.

@talexmovedtoCodidact
I enabled TRACE logging for org.hibernate and org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl logs Opened Session [....] twice, without closing any.
I included thread name in the logs and it's the same thread.
I debugged the code and confirmed that 1st session is created when invoking "doAction" and 2nd session is created when invoking the repository. After skipping the call to the static method and calling the repository directly, I retested and it worked correctly.

I was unable to reproduce it. Can you create small self contained project to demonstrate problem?

I question whether it's necessary to make this static. Since you're already using spring, make this a component.
